# Rosalind: REVP failing the given case

Tags: python, string, algorithm, rosalind

I wrote a solution to this [challenge](http://rosalind.info/problems/revp/) . It successfully handles the example case given, but not the actual case.

Challenge:
A DNA string is a reverse palindrome if it is equal to its reverse complement. For instance, GCATGC is a reverse palindrome because its reverse complement is GCATGC. For example:

> 5'...GCATGC...3'
>
> 3'...CGTACG...5'

Given:

> A DNA string of length at most 1 kbp in FASTA format.

Return:

> The position and length of every reverse palindrome in the string
>   having length between 4 and 12. You may return these pairs in any
>   order.

Sample Dataset

> >Rosalind_24 TCAATGCATGCGGGTCTATATGCAT

Sample Output

> 4 6
>
> 5 4
>
> 6 6
>
> 7 4
>
> 17 4
>
> 18 4
>
> 20 6
>
> 21 4

For the sample, it works. However it failed on the actual sample.

Actual Dataset:

`>Rosalind_7901 ATATAGTCGGCTGTCCAGGCAATCGCGAGATGGGGAACGACATCTTGGTACTTTACGGAT GCCAAGACTTAATATCTGGCCCGGATATGACCGCGAGCACCCCCTACTCGTCTGTCGGTT TCGGCCGGCATGACCTGTCCTCTTGATAATAGATATAAGTTGCCAACCGCACTATTTCAA GATCAGATGCCCCAAGGCACAAGGCACAGAAGAATCAGGTACTGAGCAAACAGCGCCCAT TTGTCAGCGCAACTCCGAGCGACAGGCACAAGTGGTAGTAACATCTGTAGTCTACGAGCG CGGGACCGATGTAAAAAGCAACGAGAGACGGGGCCGTCGATAGAAAAGCAATGGAGTCCA TATGGGCACGCTGAGCGTGCCTGTACTAATTTCTATGGGCTACTGGCACTAGGGGCTTAA GCCCTCGGTTACCGCGCTTTATGAATATAGTTTTCGTGCCAGGAGTGTCTTGTTTCGAGG AAGCGTGAGCTACACTTAGCACGTCCGGGCTTATTGGAAATTTGTTCAGTCTGTATGCTC CGCAATATCATGTCGGCGCTCATTCAATGTTGCGTGTAATTTAGACCTCTACTACAGCTG GGGTTGGAGCGGTCGGTAGTAAGACGTATGATTACGGTTTACATCCCGCCGGCGGACACG GAACGTGATTTTCAGCATTGTCCCATCGTAGGGATTGGGGCCCTAGTAGGTGTGGGTAGC ACGTTACATGAAGCTATCCAATGGCGTATATACTCCATCCCATCGGACTAGAAGATTTGA GGGACCCAGTCATAACTGGTGCAAAATTACGTTACAAAAGCCGAGGATACAGTATA`

Actual Output:

`1 4
2 4
23 6
24 4
48 4
70 4
73 4
79 4
82 4
86 4
93 4
124 6
125 4
126 6
127 4
131 4
155 4
156 4
184 4
222 4
236 4
251 4
337 4
342 4
389 4
394 4
415 4
423 4
440 4
441 4
452 4
453 4
482 4
496 4
509 4
513 4
526 6
527 4
554 4
558 4
565 4
587 4
604 6
605 4
634 4
656 10
657 8
658 6
659 4
674 4
709 6
710 4
714 4
733 4
739 4
744 4
758 8
759 4
759 6
760 4
761 4
780 4
813 4
818 4
822 4
846 4`

Code:

```
from string import maketrans
table=maketrans('ATCG','TAGC')

protein=open('rosalind_revp.txt','r').read()[14::].strip()

for i in range(len(protein)):
    for ii in range(2,7):
        if protein[i:i+ii]==protein[i+2*ii-1:i+ii-1:-1].translate(table):
            print str(i+1),str(2*ii)
```

(When testing sample, the 4th line is

`protein=open('rosalind_revp.txt','r').read()[12::].strip()`

I even manually matched a bunch of the position-length pairs, and sad to find that they all worked perfectly. I still don't know why the result wasn't accepted.
Could anyone let me know where I was wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is my github link and it has the solution hope this works

```
def reverse(l):
    t=""
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if(l[i]=='A'):
            t=t+'T'
        elif(l[i]=='T'):
            t=t+'A'
        elif(l[i]=='C'):
            t=t+'G'
        elif(l[i]=='G'):
            t=t+'C'
    return t
def rev(d):
    return d[len(d)::-1]
k=input()
p=input()
for i in range(len(p)):
    for j in range(4,14):
        if (p[i:i+j]==rev(reverse(p[i:i+j]))and i+j<=len(p)):
            print(i+1, end=" ")
            print(j)
```

https://github.com/jssssv007/stackexcahnge

Comment: Your code is not formatted properly. Also try to include some explanation/comments in your code

Comment: Bro see the code in above github link or download it.I have tested and uploaded it and it works for the above output.

Comment: I didn't say it's not working. The code you gave in answer is not formatted properly. Just format it properly so others can easily understand it